# Select query between two values in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm trying to extrat the number of a product which prices between 1 and the max product price using Laravel and query builder.

I tried with this query in phpmyadmin and it returns a result:

```
SELECT product_id ,      count( user_id ) , sum( monies ) 
   FROM products, prices
   WHERE monies
   BETWEEN '20'
   AND products.price 

   AND products.id = 101
   GROUP BY (product_id);
```

But in PHP I coudn't specify the range on which we have to search :

```
$data = Product::join('prices', 'prices.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                ->select(DB::raw('count( user_id ) as nombre'),DB::raw('sum(monies ) as sum'))
                ->where('prices.project_id', '=', '101')
                ->whereBetween('monies', array(1, 'products.price'))
                ->groupBy('prices.product_id')
                ->get();
```

But I always get an empty result and when I change `whereBetween('monies', array(1, 'products.price'))` with `whereBetween('monies', array(1, 1000))` it returns a result.

How can I use the `whereBetween`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whereBetween` requires the second element of the values array to be either a static value or a variable, but not a column from your table. You can use two `whereRaw` statements (there is no `whereBetweenRaw` equivalent), which, when used together, will create and `and` condition, i.e.:

```
    ->whereRaw('monies >= 1')->whereRaw('monies <= products.price')
```

`DB::raw` won't work in this scenario, and two regular `where` clauses won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, you're using `whereBetween()` correctly as far as I know. Two things you could try:

- Unquote `products.price` in the array
- Simply use two where clauses (>= && <=)

Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem is not related to the whereBetween it's related to the using of '`products.price`' in the whereBetween clause.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are `products.price` is being escaped as a string. Try `DB::raw('products.price')`.

Comment: it doesn't work also with `DB::raw('products.price')`

Comment: Take a look at the query it's generating by doing `toSql()` instead of `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

whereBetween() just accept integer maybe your variable is string.